# How to terminate a background while loop in Linux?

Tags: linux, perl

I cannot find a way to terminate a background `while` loop.

I started a Perl script in an infinite while loop (i.e. `while true; do perl abc.pl; done`) and my terminal session got disconnected.

Now I am trying to terminate that loop.

If I do `ps -aux | grep perl`, I see that a Perl script is running.

If I do `kill -9 <process id>`, it keeps showing up with different process IDs.

How can I terminate it for good?

The only work around I have found is to rename my script, and then it stops.

Comment: Can you reboot the machine?

Comment: Your bash process (or whatever shell you're using) is still running after you kill the Perl processes that it's starting. Find that and kill it instead.

Comment: And to stop the loop while searching for this bash, try `kill -STOP \`pidof perl\`` - it will pause (every) perl process until `-CONT` signal is sent to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What may be happening is that you are killing the perl program, but the loop throwing them off is still running. You need to kill the entire login tree.

**ps -f -u$USER** (or something like it, depends on the OS) shows the process id, parent process id, and tty of your processes.

Kill the process and the parent, all the way up the process tree to your unwanted shell running the loop. Notice the tty of the offending process... if different from your current tty kill all processes on that tty; you may need a new terminal window to get a different tty.

Alternate: Linux has **ps xjf** to show the processes in tree format... start with the relevant shell process and kill that and all child processes.

Extra info: processes that don't go away under kill -9, keeping the same PID (not your condition), are likely "zombie" processes that are waiting for their parent to read their exit status. Zombies have actually stopped and gone away and are not alive so you can't kill them. Only a ghost remains in the process table waiting for the parent to read the pending exit status. Killing the parent will reassign the process to **init**, which will read the status.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

`ps -ef` tells you two numbers. The process id, and the *parent* process id.

Kill the latter, and you'll kill the thing spawning your perl processes.

alternatively - `kill -1 -1`  will kill all your processes (don't do this as root!).